Azure AKS Kubectl tokens are working even though I have removed the role-binding?
I have an Azure AKS kubernetes cluser using Local Account with Kubernetes RBAC way of auth (no association with Entra ID it seems). Now I have some Azure apps (Enterprise Apps/App registrations) which I have rolebinded to this cluster manually via portal and then I fetch the credentials/tokens for kubectl use like this
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <app-token-secret> --tenant <teanent-id>
az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <rg> --name <cluster-name>

Now when I use kubectl it works fine.
The issue is that lots of people in the org including those who have left were given access like this above way. Now I want to revoke their access to the cluster. I have tried deleting the role binding of the app to cluster which was used to get the access but it is not working. Their kubectl token is still valid. My theory is that the token is being validated by kubernetes api server only and it does not know that the app used to get this token has been disassociated.
My question is to understand how this works behind the scenes and how can I resolve this situation ?

If tokens were generated using a specific service principal, only resetting the client secret for the app registration will render the tokens invalid.
Reset service principal credentials
az ad sp credential reset --name <appId> --query password --output tsv

